# how to save a word into a hashtable using lists:foldl

Tags: erlang

I am having two functions, one is to read in a word and save that word into the hashtable, other is a collection of words(list) that is needed to be saved in the hashtable. when i run the problem, it says "bad function function2". I know it is wrong to call function2 inside the foldl. So my question is how to use function2 inside the function3 without causing a problem. Function3 will be called first with the list as a parameter. This assignment's goal is to create a hashtable for list of words. Thank you

```
    function2(Word,HashTable)->
case lists:keyfind(Word,1,HashTable) of
    {Key,Value}->
        lists:keyreplace(Word,1,HashTable,{Word,Value+1});
    false -> 
        lists:append({Word,1},HashTable)
end.


    function3(List)->
ResultTable={}, 
lists:foldl(Function2,ResultTable,List).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `function2` in the fold. Just make sure you name it correctly:

```
lists:foldl(fun function2/2, ResultTable, List).
```

You use the construct `fun` to say that "here comes a function". `/2` must be there to specify what variant of the function you are after, since Erlang can have multiple functions by the same name and different argument lists.

You can read more about this in the manual, [Fun syntax](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79130).

Comment: Ty, now I understand more about "fun".